# UIView above UITableView scrolling effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have `UITableView` with [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh). Above this `UITableView` I have a view with `UITextField`, buttons etc.

(Ex: [image].

I would like to implement such thing: when I scroll down my tableView I would like to scroll this header too. (This could be easy created with Table header, but as I said I am using pull to refresh).  And when I start to scroll up - immediately appeared. Sorry for my poor english. Help me out.

P.S. I am using autolayout

Comment: a UITableView inside a scroll view is a bad practice, is not recommendable, the better idea is create a first cell of the table custom and move your pull refresh to above

Comment: @jose920405 Could you tell me any sources about it?

Comment: @jose920405 And As I said I want to show up this header immediatelly when scroll up